# Can I insert a section break in an Apache POI XWPFDocument?

Tags: apache-poi

With Apache POI, is it possible to add a section break to an XWPFDocument so that I can have a different XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy in different sections?

Comment: Generate different header for each Section in Apache POIFS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144210/generate-different-header-for-each-section-in-apache-poifs

Comment: That is definitely a related question, but the answer there is not a complete answer.  (I eventually decided to not try using different headers.)

Comment: What I did to solve my problem was not to use headers, but to use big headings in the up right corner. I made template where the header is just supper small. Before that I put image in the header and this image was still visible no matter how small the header was. It was OK for me, because I knew what is the content on every page, and that the content wont go on two pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may put section breaks and if you want to manipulate the content in those headers you can use  for loop
for(XWPFParagraph p : header.getParagraphs()) {}.